# Android O and Thread Local Storage for Background Services

Tags: android, multithreading, android-8.0-oreo, pjsip, thread-local-storage

I have a VOIP app on android which uses Background Services (startService). The background services is incharge of the C/C++ stack creation and lifecycle management. Since Android O, I am seeing crashes while accessing thread local storage:

```
#00 pc 000000000004bba8 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 000000000001aa13 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+54)
#02 pc 000000000001f2f9 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+24)
#03 pc 000000000001aedd /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+16)
#04 pc 00000000000808ed /data/app/com.myapp.system-TqIMuM73wCvczia_yKDs4g==/lib/arm/libpjsip.so (pj_thread_this+36)
#05 pc 000000000007ffb3 /data/app/com.myapp.system-TqIMuM73wCvczia_yKDs4g==/lib/arm/libpjsip.so (pj_log+610)
#06 pc 0000000000080215 /data/app/com.myapp.system-TqIMuM73wCvczia_yKDs4g==/lib/arm/libpjsip.so (pj_log_5+24)
#07 pc 0000000000087941 /data/app/com.myapp.system-TqIMuM73wCvczia_yKDs4g==/lib/arm/libpjsip.so (pj_timer_heap_destroy+28)
#08 pc 000000000007ad89 /data/app/com.myapp.system-TqIMuM73wCvczia_yKDs4g==/lib/arm/libpjsip.so (pj_dns_resolver_destroy+232)
#09 pc 00000000000dd418 /data/app/com.myapp.system-TqIMuM73wCvczia_yKDs4g==/lib/arm/libMyApp.so
#10 pc 00000000000dd69c /data/app/com.myapp.system-TqIMuM73wCvczia_yKDs4g==/lib/arm/libMyApp.so
```

I am using the PJSIP library and it requires the thread to be registered before using, if not it fails with an assertion. It internally uses thread local storage to manage registrations (pthread_getspecific, pthread_setspecific based).

I have registered all possible threads that could access the pjsip API especially: pj_dns_resolver_destroy. But still the thread local storage thinks that the thread is not registered. This happens only on Android 8.0+.

This makes me think if there are changes to Android O which could trigger this behavior.

**More context:**

1) pj_dns_resolver_destroy could be invoked in two cases: on network changes and on the app shutdown i.e., background service stop.

2) I use BroadcastReceiver based Network monitoring to pass the network change events which could call pj_dns_resolver_destroy.

**Additional Information:**

Service lifecycle is handled in a orderly fashion. PJSIP provides pj_thread_is_registered to check if the thread is registered, if not we register and assert. There are couple of ways my app could invoke pj_dns_resolver_destroy.

1) on network changes, either when the app is in the foreground or background. We destroy the current resolver and create a new one. The destructor calls pj_dns_resolver_destroy after checking for thread registration for PJSIP.

2) On app shutdown (could be in the foreground or background), we destroy the C++ stack from OnDestroy method of the service.

**Question:**

Are there any changes in Android O w.r.t. thread local storage or memory management w.r.t background services etc. which could trigger this behavior?

Comment: Not familiar with this library, but are you aware that You can't start background services while your app is in background (since oreo)?

Comment: Yes, came across: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background
My app is in the foreground while the background service is started, My concern is during the lifecycle of the BG service and Thread Local Storage.

Comment: In Oreo, the system is much more likely to summarily terminate background apps. But it doesn't notify you when that happens, so I'm guessing we're dealing with a more orderly `Service.onDestroy()`, that you were expecting in response to a `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`. Is that correct? Have you tried asserting that each thread you hand off to PJSIP was previously registered, or is it possible an unexpected thread could've slipped in there?

Comment: Yes, please see the additional information I added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @ssk So do you know _when_ this assert is occurring? Is it on a network change, or app shutdown? And do you mean to imply that you check `pj_thread_is_registered` prior to executing the resolver cleanup, and that check passes, but a few calls later, PJSIP asserts?